# Compile Qt3-program on KDE4

Tags: kde, compiling, qt, qt3

I want to compile a program (KTIGCC), but it is intended to be used on KDE3, using Qt3 libs. Is there any possibility of compiling and using this program in my current KDE4?

Trying to run `./configure` results in:

```
sh: 1: kde-config: not found
Project ERROR: KDE 3 kdelibs required.
```

The configure script:

```
#!/bin/bash
QMAKE_ARGS=""
if test ! -z "$1"
then case "$1" in
 --prefix=*) QMAKE_ARGS=`echo $1 | sed 's/^--prefix/PREFIX/'` ;;
esac
fi
qmake $QMAKE_ARGS
if [ $? == 127 ]; then echo "error: Qt 3 required"; fi
```

(I'm rather new to KDE, so I may not be to exact with the KDE expressions etc.)

Note: I'm not using Kubuntu, but Ubuntu with `kde-standard` installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error came from the kde(4)-config itself. Now I found out that the program isn't able to run on KDE4 at all...

I think I'll start porting it to KDE4 myself. Let's see whether I'm successful.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the first line of you error message, you need to install kde libraries for this first.

To install kde4 libraries, type <strike>`sudo apt-get install kde4-config`</strike> `sudo apt-get install kdelibs-bin` on a terminal. `kde4-config` is part of the `kdelibs-bin` package.

Comment: It says it couldn't find `kde4-config`. And yes, I'm online...

Comment: @the_Seppi: Edited my question, please recheck.

Comment: Says the newest version of `kdelibs-bin` is already installed